# How to set a default file in ajaxSubmit jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery ajaxSubmit plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit.

I don't want the user to select the file. I just want to set a file default to upload; when the user clicks confirm upload, it will get uploaded. I'm seeing no option for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. This is prohibited because of security issues. Otherwise you'll be able to steal any file from the user's computer.

Comment: Otherwise you'll be able to steal any file from the user's computer. What the value you want to set to the input? In other words what the file from the user's computer you want to get to the server?